# How to set PDF margin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Currently I am working PDF generation. I do not know how to give margin in PDF. 
I want to set PDF bottom margin 20mm. I am using `delivaryTable.SpacingAfter = 10.04f;` code

How can I do it?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236931/set-page-margins-with-itextsharp

Comment: Also cf. the [Keyword: Margins](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=44) which e.g. refers to the [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) examples [HelloWorldNarrow](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=17) demonstrating how to set margins in the `Document` constructor, and [HelloWorldMirroredMargins](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=22) demonstrating how to set margins using the `Document.setMargin` method. The corresponding c# examples can be found [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/).

Answer (score 5):

You could set the pdf margins when you instantiate the document object. Here's the syntax constructor:

```
public Document(
Rectangle pageSize,
float marginLeft,
float marginRight,
float marginTop,
float marginBottom)
```

Here's a usage example:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
```